# Working boto3 script now failing with botocore.exceptions.ClientError UnauthorizedOperation

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a script that gathers usage data from AWS, which was working flawlessly for months.

Lately, it fails, with:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeRegions operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Following is a minimal script demonstrating the issue:

```
$ python3 demonstrate_UnauthorizedOperation.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demonstrate_UnauthorizedOperation.py", line 24, in <module>
    regions = get_regions()
  File "demonstrate_UnauthorizedOperation.py", line 11, in get_regions
    ec2_responses = ec2.describe_regions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeRegions operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

$ cat demonstrate_UnauthorizedOperation.py
import boto3, botocore

def get_regions():
    region = "us-east-1"
    region = "ap-northeast-1"
    region = "us-west-1"
    regions = dict()

    ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name=region)
    ec2_responses = ec2.describe_regions()

    ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=region)
    for resp in ec2_responses['Regions']:
        region_id = resp['RegionName']
        tmp = '/aws/service/global-infrastructure/regions/%s/longName' % region_id
        ssm_response = ssm_client.get_parameter(Name = tmp)
        region_name = ssm_response['Parameter']['Value'] 
        regions[region_id] = region_name
    return(regions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    regions = get_regions()

$ cat ~/.aws/credentials 
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxIAJVMBEFxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxMmperMqxxxxoR9R6ONjxx

[SoftLayer]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxJ2zaY1lwbxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxFxRfagJwxxxxKnEMWLK

[qa@vestal ~]$ cat ~/.aws/client_secret.json 
{"installed":{"client_id":"360000009942-umxxxxxx3mr2s03nl9g8l9odi.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"amiable-shuttle-190016","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"pxxxxxxxg-zyxx6_nxxW","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
$
```

Any ideas on how to debug this failure to authenticate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not having a failure to authenticate, you have a failure to be authorized.  The user you are running the script as needs to have the `ec2:DescribeRegions` IAM permission.